# Can we do row operation using pandas in pyspark?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

```
import numpy as np
def charging_funct(rating , duration):
    lst = rating.values
    for x in np.nditer(lst):
        if x > 3.5: # x will contain only value
            return duration * rating

    charging = pandas_udf(charging_funct , returnType = DoubleType())
    df_2.select(charging(col("Rating"),col("Duration"))).show()
```

The above function is incorrect but have included the code to help explain my question:

Suppose i have to return `duration * rating` if the rating of movies is greater than 3.5 and just return `duration` otherwise.
Is this possible with `pandas_udf` in `pyspark`? Comparing each row individually will not be efficient as pandas work on batch data.

Comment: Please add imports for `pandas_udf` and `DoubleType`.

Comment: It'll be better if you can provide some sample data with expected output.